# Бот на selenium. Python

Tags: python

Есть ли что-то лучше selenium, если мне нужно парсить и нажимать на элементы DOM'a.

Открытый браузер не обязателен(скорее не нужен).

Если ли более хорошие варианты для этого?

Comment: Вам не нужен в браузере в принципе, или вы можете использовать headless?